# Python os.popen quotes within quotes error

Tags: python

I have the following command, but it does not work. Can anyone help what the issue.

```
cur_usage=os.popen("""df -k \tmp |tail -1 | awk '{{print $4"\n"$5}}'| grep '%'|tr -d '%'""").read()
print(cur_usage)
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. You could improve this question by providing the error information you receive when running this. With that said, I'd expect `\tmp` to be `/tmp` with a forward slash.

Comment: Still not working after fixing to /tmp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to do here:

1. If you're on a Unix-like OS, you should change `\tmp` to `/tmp`
2. You need to either change `\n` to `\\n` or mark the string as a raw string.

One of either of the following should work for you:

```
curr_usage = os.popen("""df -k /tmp |tail -1 | awk '{{print $4"\\n"$5}}'| grep '%'|tr -d '%'""").read().strip()
```

or

```
curr_usage = os.popen(r"""df -k /tmp |tail -1 | awk '{{print $4"\n"$5}}'| grep '%'|tr -d '%'""").read().strip()
```